# Сохранение вложений с почты на python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imap

Скачиваю xls файлы из вложений и сохраняю в папку, но почему-то некоторые письма не видят файлы, хотя они в письме есть.

пример того, как видеться тип и имя файла

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
=?UTF-8?B?0JrQu9C10Y8sINC80LDRgdC70LAsINGB0LjQu9C40LrQvtC9IDIwMTcgKDEpLnhscw==?
```

И сам код:

```
import imaplib
import email.message
import os.path
import datetime
import xlrd

YA_HOST = "imap.yandex.ru"
YA_PORT = 993
YA_USER = "lapithome"
YA_PASSWORD = "blabla"

pause_time = 5000


class Getmail():
    """ClientTask"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 1

    def yandex(self,sender):

        # подключились к почте и логинимся
        imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(YA_HOST)
        imap.login(YA_USER, YA_PASSWORD)
        status, select_data = imap.select()
        # nmessages = select_data[0].decode('utf-8')

        # от кого письмо
        status, search_data = imap.search(None, 'FROM', sender)

        for msg_id in reversed(search_data[0].split()):
            status, msg_data = imap.fetch(msg_id, '(RFC822)')
        # включает в себя заголовки и альтернативные полезные нагрузки
            mail = email.message_from_bytes(msg_data[0][1])

            if mail.is_multipart():
                filelist = []
                path = './xls/' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + '/'
                if not os.path.exists(path):
                    os.makedirs(path)
                for part in mail.walk():
                    content_type = part.get_content_type()
                    filename = part.get_filename()
                    if filename:
                        print(content_type)
                        print(filename)
                        if '.xls' in filename:
                            filelist.append(filename)
                            print('Закачали файл: ', filename)

                            with open(path+part.get_filename(), 'wb') as new_file:
                                new_file.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                break
        imap.expunge()
        imap.logout()
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался: 
заголовок base64 и нужно его декодировать:

```
import base64
for part in mail.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart' or part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
        continue

    filename = part.get_filename()

    # Find non-ascii filenames and decode

    transfer_encoding = part.get_all('Content-Transfer-Encoding')
    if transfer_encoding and transfer_encoding[0] == 'base64':
        filename_parts = filename.split('?')
        filename = base64.b64decode(filename_parts[3]).decode(filename_parts[1])
```